# Qt mouse movement/action combination

Tags: qt

How to manage combined mouse movement (for example left click + midle click + left click release)

I have the method `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` but I did not find the way to combine them.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a QWidget which display something, this display can be manipulated (move, pan, zoom) and I try to use only the mouse. This make 5 actions (move, pan, zoom, select and right click) and only 3 buttons on the mouse. This is why I try to combine mouse movement for each action : L + M - L = move, Midle only = pan, L + M = zoom, Left = select, Right = property.

Comment: You could store the last event from mousePressEvent as a class variable, and then build them from there, but I'd really recommend looking at a different solution for it.

Comment: Maybe you could use [`QMouseEvent::buttons()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qmouseevent.html#buttons) in your `mouseMoveEvent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to combine the information from `mousePress` and `mouseRelease` you need to somehow keep track which button is still pressed and which one has already been released again.

Below is a rather simply example which seems to do what you describe (actions indicated by printouts)

Let me know if this helps

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QtCore>


class MyGraphicsView: public QGraphicsView
{
public:
  MyGraphicsView( QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent = 0) : QGraphicsView(scene,parent)
  {
    active[Qt::LeftButton] = false;
    active[Qt::RightButton] = false;
    active[Qt::MiddleButton] = false;
  }

public slots:
  virtual void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event );
  virtual void mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent * event );

  std::map< Qt::MouseButton, bool > active;

};

void MyGraphicsView::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
{
  active[event->button()] = true;

  if( event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && !active[Qt::MiddleButton] && !active[Qt::RightButton]) {
    qDebug() << "select";
  } else if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton && !active[Qt::LeftButton] && !active[Qt::MiddleButton] ) {
    qDebug() << "property";
  } else if ( event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && active[Qt::MiddleButton] && !active[Qt::RightButton]) {
    qDebug() << "zoom";
  } else if ( event->button() == Qt::MiddleButton && !active[Qt::LeftButton] && !active[Qt::RightButton] ) {
    qDebug() << "pan";
  }

}

void MyGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
{
  if( event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && active[Qt::LeftButton] && active[Qt::MiddleButton] ){
    qDebug() << "move";
  }
  active[event->button()] = false;
}



int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    scene.setSceneRect( -100.0, -100.0, 200.0, 200.0 );

    MyGraphicsView view( &scene );
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```